# Checking whether NumPy array is in Python list

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, contains

I have a list of of numpy arrays, and I would like to check whether a given array is in the list.  There is some very strange behavior with this, and I'm wondering how to get around it.  Here's a simple version of the problem:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1,1])
a = [x,1]

x in a        # Returns True
(x+1) in a    # Throws ValueError
1 in a        # Throws ValueError
```

I don't understand what is going on here.  Is there a good workaround to this problem?

I'm working with Python 3.7.

Edit: The exact error is:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.  Use a.any() or a.all()
```

My numpy version is 1.18.1.

Comment: Can you provide the full error and the version for numpy as well?

Comment: I get a `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.` even with the first check `x in a`

Comment: @cicolus Edited.

Comment: @norok2 Apologies, I made some modifications to the code in the OP that I thought were unimportant, but turned out to matter.  I have rectified that now.  However, it makes the problem even stranger to me...

Answer (score 1):

(**EDIT**: to include a more general and perhaps cleaner approach)

One way around it is to implement a NumPy safe version of `in`:

```
import numpy as np


def in_np(x, items):
    for item in items:
        if isinstance(x, np.ndarray) and isinstance(item, np.ndarray) \
                and x.shape == item.shape and np.all(x == item):
            return True
        elif isinstance(x, np.ndarray) or isinstance(item, np.ndarray):
            pass
        elif x == item:
            return True
    return False
```

```
x = np.array([1, 1])
a = [x, 1]

for y in (x, 0, 1, x + 1, np.array([1, 1, 1])):
    print(in_np(y, a))
# True
# False
# True
# False
# False
```

---

Or, even better, to write a version of `in` with an arbitrary comparison (possibly defaulting to the default `in` behavior), and then make use of `np.array_equal()` which has a semantic that is compliant with the expected behavior for `==`. In code:

```
import operator


def in_(x, items, eq=operator.eq):
    for item in items:
        if eq(x, item):
            return True
    return False
```

```
x = np.array([1, 1])
a = [x, 1]

for y in (x, 0, 1, x + 1, np.array([1, 1, 1])):
    print(in_(y, a, np.array_equal))
# True
# False
# True
# False
# False
```

---

Finally, note that `items` can be any iterable, but the complexity of the operation will not be `O(1)` for hashing containers like `set()`, although it would still be giving correct results:

```
print(in_(1, {1, 2, 3}))
# True
print(in_(0, {1, 2, 3}))
# False

in_(1, {1: 2, 3: 4})
# True
in_(0, {1: 2, 3: 4})
# False
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `in` is more or less interpreted as

```
def in_sequence(elt, seq):
    for i in seq:
        if elt == i:
            return True
    return False
```

And `1 == x` does not give `False` but raises an Exception because internally numpy converts it to an array of booleans. It does make sense in most contextes but here it gives a stupid behaviour.

It sounds like a bug, but is not easy to fix. Processing `1 == np.array(1, 1)` the same as `np.array(1, 1) == np.array(1, 1)` is a major feature of numpy. And delegating equality comparisons to classes is a major feature of Python. So I cannot even imagine what should be the correct behaviour.

TL/DR: Never mix Python lists and numpy arrays because they have very different semantics and the mix leads to inconsistent corner cases.

Comment: NumPy is breaking the "contract" that the result of `==` is a `bool`. It does so in the name of readability. This is mainly due to the (semi-forced) design choice of implicit broadcasting. While it also provides [`array_equal()`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html), which has the semantic that Python would expect from `==`.  A clean solution to this would be to introduce a new operator, e.g. `===`, (pretty much like it was done for `@`) which has the semantic of the current `==` and let `==` behave like `array_equal()`. But it would take 10 years for this.

Comment: And I am confident that there are other places where the implicit broadcasting is lurking to show up as a *bug*, e.g. with the greater/smaller behavior (although their impact may not be as detrimental).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so:

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1,1])
a = np.array([x.tolist(), 1])

x in a # True
(x+1) in a # False
1 in a # True
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `x in [1,x]`, python will compare `x` with each of the elements in the list, and during the comparison `x == 1`, the result will be a numpy array:

```
>>> x == 1
array([ True,  True])
```

and interpreting this array as a `bool` value will trigger the error due to inherent ambiguity:

```
>>> bool(x == 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```